# R how Sum values by group by date

Tags: r

I have this table  already in variable DATA in R, loaded from csv

```
country, date, confirmed    
Afghanistan, 2020-03-16, 21
Afghanistan, 2020-03-17, 22
Afghanistan, 2020-03-18, 22
Albania, 2020-03-16, 23
Albania, 2020-03-17, 33
Albania, 2020-03-18, 38
...
```

I would like to make this query in R

`` select  date, sum(confirmed) as confirmed   FROM `Table` group by date ``

Any idea pls ?

So results should be this

```
date,confirmed
2020-03-16, 44
2020-03-17, 55
2020-03-18, 60
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(confirmed ~ date, Table, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Table %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(confirmed = sum(confirmed, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` implementation :

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(Table)
Table[,.(confirmed = sum(confirmed)), by = date]
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I edited :)